# Sign a public key with a CA private key

Tags: go, ssh, rsa, pki

I am trying to implement the function performed by the command
`ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I <some name>  -n <some principal>  -V -start:+end ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in Go. Here is my code

```
    userPublicKey, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(userPublicKeyBytes)
    privPem, _ := pem.Decode(caPrivateKeyBytes)
    caPrivateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(privPem.Bytes)

    signer, err := ssh.NewSignerFromKey(caPrivateKey)

    permissions := ssh.Permissions{
        CriticalOptions: map[string]string{},
        Extensions: map[string]string{ "permit-agent-forwarding": ""},
    }

    cert := ssh.Certificate{
        CertType: ssh.UserCert, Permissions: permissions, Key: userPublicKey,
    }

    err = cert.SignCert(rand.Reader, signer)
    log.Println(string(cert.Marshal()))
```

The result is a certificate (when marshalled) starts as expected, with `ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com`, but instead of the base64 encoded contents, I get weird symbols:

```
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com -`"�3�c�u�u.�X��&S�_^)�u��:�jJ�Đz��'B��~�A��ŷ�
6հ�@���%T��� m�����*Erkq�y��Z����t&so1TTmCt��k��f���:�Lr�
tI`��>�%���!R��<�`M>��3���BhR�ٚ./�*Pk�#���Bd�,k���W+G�P���;��IQ
                                        6$�)�k#ㄆ�]G�"�tذ&Mh>(8���-�
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docs state: _`Marshal returns the serialized key data in SSH wire format`_, but you're not sending this over the wire. I believe `ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey` will output the desired format.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. That actually solved my problem.
I was able to wotk around it with 
`fmt.Sprintf("ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com %s", encoder.EncodeToString(cert.Marshal()))`
But yours is a better solution :)